# How can I return the combination of two borrowed RefCells?

Tags: rust, iterator, borrowing

I have a struct with two `Vec`s wrapped in `RefCell`s. I want to have a method on that struct that combines the two vectors and returns them as a new `RefCell` or `RefMut`:

```rust
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut};

struct World {
    positions: RefCell<Vec<Option<Position>>>,
    velocities: RefCell<Vec<Option<Velocity>>>,
}

type Position = i32;
type Velocity = i32;

impl World {
    pub fn new() -> World {
        World {
            positions: RefCell::new(vec![Some(1), None, Some(2)]),
            velocities: RefCell::new(vec![None, None, Some(1)]),
        }
    }

    pub fn get_pos_vel(&self) -> RefMut<Vec<(Position, Velocity)>> {
        let mut poses = self.positions.borrow_mut();
        let mut vels = self.velocities.borrow_mut();

        poses
            .iter_mut()
            .zip(vels.iter_mut())
            .filter(|(e1, e2)| e1.is_some() && e2.is_some())
            .map(|(e1, e2)| (e1.unwrap(), e2.unwrap()))
            .for_each(|elem| println!("{:?}", elem));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let world = World::new();

    world.get_pos_vel();
}
```

How would I return the zipped contents of the vectors as a new `RefCell`? Is that possible?

I know there is `RefMut::map()` and I tried to nest two calls to `map`, but didn't succeed with that.

Comment: Additionally, your `.filter().map()` should probably just be `.filter_map` and avoid the `unwrap`s.

Comment: Sorry, my brain already melted, when I posted this. I provided a minimal example that doesn't compile, but I think shows, what I try to do. The other answers you linked, didn't helped me for this particular problem.

Comment: I agree with the answer: if you want to return a new `Vec`, it doesn't need to be wrapped in any kind of `Ref*`. Why do you believe you want such a signature?

Comment: @Shepmaster This is not about the `Vec`. I want to return mutable references to elements inside these vecs. And I don't see any way to do this. The answer creates a new `Vec` with new, copied elements, not references. If the caller changes a value in the returned `Vec`, this value won't change in `World`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be able to modify the positions and velocities. If these have to be stored in two separate `RefCell`s, what about side-stepping the problem and using a callback to do the modification?

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct World {
    positions: RefCell<Vec<Option<Position>>>,
    velocities: RefCell<Vec<Option<Velocity>>>,
}

type Position = i32;
type Velocity = i32;

impl World {
    pub fn new() -> World {
        World {
            positions: RefCell::new(vec![Some(1), None, Some(2)]),
            velocities: RefCell::new(vec![None, None, Some(1)]),
        }
    }

    pub fn modify_pos_vel<F: FnMut(&mut Position, &mut Velocity)>(&self, mut f: F) {
        let mut poses = self.positions.borrow_mut();
        let mut vels = self.velocities.borrow_mut();

        poses
            .iter_mut()
            .zip(vels.iter_mut())
            .filter_map(|pair| match pair {
                (Some(e1), Some(e2)) => Some((e1, e2)),
                _ => None,
            })
            .for_each(|pair| f(pair.0, pair.1))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let world = World::new();

    world.modify_pos_vel(|position, velocity| {
        // Some modification goes here, for example:
        *position += *velocity;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a new `Vec`, then you don't need to wrap it in `RefMut` or `RefCell`:

### Based on your code with `filter` and `map`

```rust
pub fn get_pos_vel(&self) -> Vec<(Position, Velocity)> {
    let mut poses = self.positions.borrow_mut();
    let mut vels = self.velocities.borrow_mut();

    poses.iter_mut()
        .zip(vels.iter_mut())
        .filter(|(e1, e2)| e1.is_some() && e2.is_some())
        .map(|(e1, e2)| (e1.unwrap(), e2.unwrap()))
        .collect()
}
```

### Alternative with `filter_map`

```rust
poses.iter_mut()
    .zip(vels.iter_mut())
    .filter_map(|pair| match pair {
        (Some(e1), Some(e2)) => Some((*e1, *e2)),
        _ => None,
    })
    .collect()
```

You can wrap it in `RefCell` with `RefCell::new`, if you really want to, but I would leave it up to the user of the function to wrap it in whatever they need.

Comment: Now I got your code running and I found out, why it works: `Position` and `Velocity` in my example are `Copy`, but my actual types are not. Also I don't want to perform a copy there. I want to get real references to the values, that's why I want to return a kind of `RefCell`. The point of this function is that the caller can change values inside `World`.

Comment: You should decide what exactly you want to return. A vector of tuples containing references? An iterator may be even better.

Comment: As long as the caller can change values in  `World` through the return value, it doesn't matter. `Iterator`, `Vector`, `Tuple`... whatever solves the problem. I tried a lot of approaches using `RefMut::map`, but none of them worked. `RefMut::map_split` has been added in 1.35 and does exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to do. Something like `RefMut::merge` would be helpful here.